# 'useEffect', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.ts(7010)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, native

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const cont = async () => {
      const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status === 'granted') {
        const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
          fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
        });

        if (data.length > 0) {
          const contact = data[0];
          console.log(contact);
        }
        
      }
      
    }();
  }, []);
```

please help im relatively new to typescript and im not sure why this error is occuring

Comment: Your code currently throws a SyntaxError due to the `}();` at the end

Answer (score -1):

You invoke the function like this:

```
(() => {
   const { status } = await Contacts.requestPermissionsAsync();
   if (status === 'granted') {
       const { data } = await Contacts.getContactsAsync({
       fields: [Contacts.Fields.Emails],
    });
          
    if (data.length > 0) {
        const contact = data[0];
        console.log(contact);
     }        
   }                   
})();
```